# What is the reasoning behind this exponents question?

Tags: notation, exponentiation

What is $3^{3^{3}}?$

Plugging $3^{3^{3}} $into the calculator gives 7625597484987. 
I believe because this implies that 
 $3^{3^{3}}=3^{27}$, is this true?

And plugging $(3^{3})^{3}$ gives 19683, because $
(3^{3})^{3}=3^{3}\times 3^{3}\times 3^{3}=3^{9}=19683$

So which one is the correct answer, and why?

Comment: People find the notation confusing, but $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$ and not $(a^b)^c$, which of course is just $a^{bc}$.  In practice, I think it's best to add the parentheses, as omitting them always leads to confusion.

Comment: You can interpret that there is no reason to read $3^{3^3}$ as $(3^3)^3$ because we can express it as $3^{3\cdot3}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, by the standard order of operations, $a^{b^c}$ has to be $a^{(b^c)}$, not $(a^b)^c$, since, barring parentheses, exponents are to be evaluated before the rest of the expression. So you have to evaluate the exponent of $a$, that is, $b^c$, before you can evaluate $a$ being raised to that exponent.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That "exponents are to be evaluated before the rest of the expression" could just as well justify the claim that "$a^b$ must be evaluated first, so that you can evaluate it being raised to the exponent $c$," couldn't it?. While I agree that that $a{b^c}$ must be $a^{(b^c)}$ and not $(a^b)^c$, I'm not sure that "exponents are to be evaluated before the rest of the expression" requires it.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - no, the rule is *exponents* are evaluated first, not exponentiations. That is, whatever is *in the exponent* must be evaluated before the exponentiation is evaluated. $b^c$ is the exponent of $a$. $a^b$ is not the exponent of $c$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok, I'd misunderstood what you meant by exponents first. But even with the correct understanding, you'd still have to know how to parse $a^{b^c}$ beforehand right? If incorrectly read as $(a^b)^c$, we'd evaluate $c$ first (it is the the exponent) and then the base, $a^b$, which requires evaluation of b, then a, and so on. I still don't see how the exponents first rule tells us how to parse the expression in the first place.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - mea culpa. You are correct in this. It is still ambiguous without the specific rule for exponential towers.

Comment: @paulsinclair OK, I just want sure if i was missing something.  I understand why our convention is what it is, i just didn't see it as following from the evaluation order.

Comment: Please stop confusing “operator precedence” with “evaluation order”.  Precedence means that $f(x) + g(x) · h(x)$ is equivalent to $f(x) + (g(x) · h(x))$.  It is not an instruction to evaluate $g$ and $h$ before $f$.  And both are separate from “associativity”, which is the issue in this question.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You can't solve the leftmost exponent in a^b^c first, because you don't have a value for b yet until you've solved the rightmost exponent. Trying to solve from left to right is just raising 3 to 3^3 - which is again just a(bc).

Comment: @kurja I understand *why* our convention is that a^b^c (and I'm purposely avoiding math mode here because TeX requires us to make the grouping explicit), is parsed as a^(b^c); if we parsed as (a^b)^c, then it'd be equivalent to a^(b*c). My point is that, as far I can tell, "evaluate the exponent first" doesn't dictate the parsing convention. Whether we parse as (a^b)^c or a^(b^c), we can still evaluate our exponents first. Like Dan said in a comment, this really seems to be about associativity, not evaluation order.

Answer (score 63):

Unlike addition and multiplication, exponentiation is not *[associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)*:

- $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$
- $(a\times b)\times c=a\times (b\times c)$

but

- ($a$^$b$)^$c\ne a\!$^($b$^$c$), more commonly written as: $\left(a^b\right)^c \ne a^{\left( b^c \right)}$

This means there's no risk in simply writing "$a+b+c$" or "$a \times b \times c$" since the order in which you perform the operations doesn't matter in both cases.

For exponentiation this is not the case and writing "$a$^$b$^$c$" is ambiguous, but we do have:

$$\color{blue}{\left(a^b\right)^c = a^{bc}} \ne a^{\left( b^c \right)}$$

Because we have this property (in blue), it's common to interpret $a^{b^c}$ as $a^{\left( b^c \right)}$ but if you want to avoid confusion, you can always add the parentheses.

Comment: What a thoughtful explanation. I really appreciate this!

Comment: You're welcome, Meghan, and welcome to MSE.

Comment: I don't think $a^{b^c}$ is ambiguous any more than $a-b-c$ is ambiguous. Neither operation is associative, but in both cases there are definite rules for which order to perform them in.

Comment: If you're referring to "left to right", I can see how $a-b-c$ is clear but I don't agree it is (equally) obvious for $a^{b^c}$. But if you mean there is a separate rule or convention that implies $a^{b^c}$ is to be interpreted as $a^{\left( b^c \right)}$, then it's my feeling this isn't as (universally) known.

Comment: @StackTD I'm not sure if it's "obvious" but there would be no point writing $a^{b^c}$ if it just meant $a^{bc}$. Obviously, it does confuse people but I find that as soon as you mention that $(a^b)^c$ is just $a^{bc}$, people are happy that $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$ and that the parentheses in the latter are redundant.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime It's not about which order to *perform* them in though, it's about the [precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) of the operators involved. Subtraction is conventionally left-associative, so `a - b - c - d` is `((a - b) - c) - d`. The *precedence* of multiplication is higher than that of subtraction, so `a - b - c * d` is `(a - b) - (c * d)`. But you can *evaluate* either $a-b$ or $c \times d$ first. Evaluation order isn't the same as precedence and operator associativity.

Comment: @StackTD Yes,  there's a separate rule for powers which is "top to bottom". I wasn't intending to suggest it's the same rule in both cases. And it's certainly not as well known as the $a-b-c$ rule, but that's largely because far fewer people deal with exponentiation on any sort of regular basis.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor There's a reason your example has three operations. If you only have two, as in the case I was talking about, then there isn't really a distinction between precedence and evaluation order.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: Even for people who do regularly deal with exponentiation, it's usually in a one-operation-at-a-time context like $10^{12}$ or $x^2$.  *Chained* exponentiation is much less common.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer is not completely explicit, but the reason why $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$ is not purely mathematical, but conventional. We **chose** to use the exponentiation notation in this manner, namely the whole superscripted expression is the exponent, like this: $a^\boxed{b^c}$. And it is **important** to note that we can make such a convention because it is **unambiguous**; you can always make it clear by the superscript formatting what is supposed to be the exponent.

As StackTD said, addition and multiplication are associative, and hence it is not problematic to use a linear notation and omit brackets. In contrast, exponentiation is not associative, so it makes sense to use this kind of non-linear notation so that we can still omit brackets! You can imagine the superscript formatting as literally standing in for the bracketing.

Similarly for other notation issues; the first step is to know precisely what is the convention for interpreting the notation. For example, $-2^3$ is by convention interpreted as $-(2^3)$ because exponentiation is given higher precedence than negation, and $2+3·4 = 14$ because $·$ has higher precedence than $+$.

Comment: hi, I would use $-2^2$ because $(-2)^3$ is $-2^3$.

Comment: @Alucard: Lol! You are right, of course! I wasn't computing when I wrote that. =)

Answer (score 0):

a^b^c and (a^b)^c are different because (a^b)^c is the same as a^b multiplied by itself $c$ times. a^b^c is rather confusing, so you should use parentheses like this: a^(b^c), which is $a$ multiplied by itself b^c times. a^b^c should have parentheses just to avoid confusion.